# Can someone explain this recursive function MongooseJS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, recursion, mongoose

I have had a look at [this](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/d44a97405bbe58730f3c397f504634a504d3e6e9/core/server/models/base.js#L321) function.

I can see that it generates a slug, but I dont quite understand how it works.
On line `327` it returns the promise from the `Model.findOne` function, but inside the callback of that `Model.findOne`function, they recursively call the outer function that starts at line `321`again.

Can anyone help me? I need to generate some unique slugs as well, and this seems like a solution - if I can understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checkIfSlugExists` function in your example ensures that there is no documents with `slugToFind` slug in database already.

`checkIfSlugExists` not simply checks that the slug if vacant, but it also has some failover mechanisms. So, in the end it returns a promise to a vacant slug:

1. If `slugToFind` don't exist in database, then it's returned (line `331`).
2. Otherwise `checkIfSlugExists` checks for a `longSlug` (lines `338-341`), which is just a longer version of the original `slugToFind`.
3. If both `slugToFind` and `longSlug` are already taken, then `checkIfSlugExists` starts adding numbers to `longSlug` (line `344-355`), starting from 2, untill it finds a vacant slug.

Every time `checkIfSlugExists` wants to check for some new slug it recursively calls itself with this new value.

Comment: The thing that gets me confused is mainly the recursive function calls inside a promise. It returns a promise inside a promise inside a promise ... ?

Comment: Yes. When you're chaining a promise with `.then`, the resulting promise will be resolved with the value, returned from `.then` callback. But, when you return a promise from `.then` callback, it gets resolved first.

Comment: So, the promise, returned from first `checkIfSlugExists` call, will be resolved with the value of the last promise returned in this recursive chain.